# What start_date should I use for a manually triggered DAG?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Many of the [airflow example dags](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/master/airflow/example_dags) that have `schedule_interval=None` set a dynamic start date like [`airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2)`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_bash_operator.py#L30) or [`datetime.utcnow()`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_trigger_target_dag.py#L46). However, the [docs](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date) recommend against a dynamic start date:

> We recommend against using dynamic values as start_date, especially datetime.now() as it can be quite confusing. The task is triggered once the period closes, and in theory an @hourly DAG would never get to an hour after now as now() moves along.

Is start date irrelevant for manually triggered dags? What is the best practice here?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm clear on what the problem you're encountering is.  Can you add more context to your question around what you're trying to achieve, like specifically if a dynamic `start_date` is not working for you?  The approach you described seems fine to me as `start_date` isn't too important for a DAG that's only externally triggered.  This is a good question because I don't think the current docs make this use case explicitly clear.

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston no observable problem, just a conflict between docs and examples that make me feel unsure as the user. The tutorial talks about start_date a lot so I wasn't confident that it was really irrelevant.

Answer (score 7):

I always try to set the start date for manually triggered DAGS as the day I first ran it so that I know when the DAG would have first been run for reference in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `schedule_interval=None` I believe the `start_date` is irrelevant as airflow will not attempt to perform any back filling. Just set it to anything even if it's a dynamic one it shouldn't cause any hassle.

Comment: I would not recommend this. Even for manually triggered DAGs, you may want to manually backfill, e.g. with the `airflow backflow` command. If the dynamic start date is *after* the chosen backfill date, it will block your tasks.

Comment: I don’t fully understand why you would want to manually trigger a backfill for a DAG that has no interval defined but okay. And yes you obviously need to be sure the start date is in the past even if it is dynamic

Comment: We do it when we need the `execution_date` to be in the past.

Comment: when you manually trigger the dag with trigger_dag you can provide an execution date there.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just setting `start_date` to 1970, Jan 1st (absurdly far in the past) so that Airflow never complains that the execution date is before the start date.